# SQL Plus: How to prevent the auto rounding of the number

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a requirement to pull the Oracle db values to csv using SQL Plus to compare a numeric values which has a decimal point of 10 digits.

But the the numbers are rounding automatically to 8 decimal point. Is there any way we can disable the rounding of numbers in SQLPlus. Below find the details.

[image]

Here is my SQL Set commands.

```
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET WRAP OFF
SET COLSEP ,     -- SEPARATE COLUMNS WITH A COMMA
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TRIMS ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET DEFINE ON
SET termout ON
SET verify ON
SET linesize 600
```

Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: Please [post text not images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numeric values don't have any intrinsic format, so your client is deciding how to display them. I'm not sure which client is producing the 'DB' values, but the SQL*Plus ones are just [using its defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref551):

> SQL*Plus normally displays numbers with as many digits as are required for accuracy, up to a standard display width determined by the value of the `NUMWIDTH` variable of the `SET` command (normally 10). If a number is larger than the value of `SET NUMWIDTH`, SQL*Plus rounds the number up or down to the maximum number of characters allowed if possible, or displays hashes if the number is too large.

So you see:

```
with your_table (x, y) as (
            select -0.0224231886, -0.021470109  from dual
  union all select -0.037164512,  -0.0238026527 from dual
  union all select  0.021786217,   0.044550243  from dual
  union all select  0.0772262609,  0.0724136521 from dual
  union all select  0.968632046,   0.0866250777 from dual
)
select x, y from your_table;

        X,         Y
-.02242319,-.02147011
-.03716451,-.02380265
.021786217,.044550243
.077226261,.072413652
.968632046,.086625078
```

You can change the default for your session with [`set numf[ormat]'](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG093), using a format model with enough digits before and after the decimal point to represent any number you might have stored, e.g.:

```
set numformat 990.99999999999
```

then the same query gets

```
              X,              Y
  -0.0224231886,  -0.0214701090
  -0.0371645120,  -0.0238026527
   0.0217862170,   0.0445502430
   0.0772262609,   0.0724136521
   0.9686320460,   0.0866250777
```

Or you could implicitly modify it using [`set numw[idth]`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG094):

```
set numf ""
set numwidth 20

                   X,                   Y
        -.0224231886,         -.021470109
         -.037164512,        -.0238026527
          .021786217,          .044550243
         .0772262609,         .0724136521
          .968632046,         .0866250777
```

which gives you the precision you need, but doesn't show the leading zero. If that doesn't matter then this approach is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the update. set numwidth 20 has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you seek for column formating option to enforce column formating

```
COLUMN column_name FORMAT 999999.0000000000
```